# Bootstrap datetimepicker issue instide a table-responsive class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using this (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) Date and time picker for my website, and when you open the datetime picker in a table-responsive class it does not show the date picker on top  the table unless in the css you add .table-responsive { overflow:visible !important } in the css. Its all well and good doing this, but then when you shrink the screen or use it on a mobile / tablet, the table is no longer responsive and hangs off the side of the screen.

Please see this (https://jsfiddle.net/daza110/6abxn644/3/) fiddle which shows it opening correctly until you shrink the screen.

And please see this (https://jsfiddle.net/daza110/6abxn644/4/) fiddle which shrinks the table correctly, but does not show the calendar properly.

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped text-center bgwhite" id="accountTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-2">Debt Ref</th>
          <th class="col-sm-2">Due Date</th>
          <th class="col-sm-2">Amount Paid</th>
          <th class="col-sm-2">Account</th>
          <th class="col-sm-2">Reconcile Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="armitage">
          <td>
            <div>NOR087-DAN052</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>05/01/2016</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>180.00</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">Paralegal (951)</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Reconcile Date" name="dates[ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473]" id="dates-ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473" class="form-control ">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery('#dates-ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473').datetimepicker({
  format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
});
```

UPDATE

I hacked this but it isnt nice, I added a PHP function that attaches a DatePicker and then did the following jquery code, this removes the table-responsive and adds a temp class on show then on hide removes temp class and adds the table-responsive again:

```
function attachDatePick($fieldId)
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function()
        {
            jQuery('#<?echo $fieldId;?>').datetimepicker().on('dp.show',function()
            {
                jQuery(this).closest('.table-responsive').removeClass('table-responsive').addClass('temp');
            }).on('dp.hide',function()
            {
                jQuery(this).closest('.temp').addClass('table-responsive').removeClass('temp')
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I am encountering this as well when the parent div has overflow:hidden but I can't figure out how to avoid it without breaking my layout.

Comment: @Wammy - See my update

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand too much what you need but is maybe this?

```
.table-responsive {
 overflow-x: inherit;
}
```

See in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6abxn644/7/)

Comment: When you click on the date field, the datepicker popup shows behind the table, not on top

Answer (score 0):

easy way is setting `position: static` for datepicker wrapper. For instance

```
<td>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Reconcile Date" name="dates[ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473]" id="dates-ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473" class="form-control ">
            </div>
          </td>
```

you can set `.col-sm-12 {position: static}`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any answer about this question that really pleases.

So I adapted a another code for bootstrap dropdown with same problem inside .table-responsive

below is the main code, that I put on window:

```js
window.setDatapickerEvents = ($parentElement) => {
    $($parentElement).on('dp.show', function (e) {
        const $e = $(e.target);
        const $input = $e.find('input').first();
        const $btn = $e.find('span.input-group-addon').first();
        const $dropdownMenu = $e.find('.dropdown-menu');

        const eOffset = $e.offset();
        const btnWidth = $btn.outerWidth();
        const inputWidth = $input.outerWidth();
        const dropdownWidth = $dropdownMenu.outerWidth();
        const dropdownHeight = $dropdownMenu.outerHeight();

        $('body').append($dropdownMenu.detach());

        $dropdownMenu.css({
            'top': eOffset.top - dropdownHeight,
            'left': eOffset.left + inputWidth + (btnWidth / 2) - dropdownWidth + 20,
            'width': dropdownWidth,
            'height': dropdownHeight,
        });
    });

    $($parentElement).on('dp.hide', function (e) {
        const $e = $(e.target);
        const $dropdownMenu = $e.find('.dropdown-menu');

        $e.append($dropdownMenu.detach());
        $dropdownMenu.hide();
    });
}
```

And to enable it inside scripts tag in your page

```js
setDatapickerEvents('.table-responsive');
```

[Before - Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0z2O.png)
[After - Resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOrPQ.png)

I hope it helps anyone